# (String): Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_verify()

Tags: php, string

I encountered a Problem when Logging in to a php webpanel which i configured.
I configured the database and everything correctly, but each time i try to login, it shows the below response.:

" string(4) "test" string(4) "test" 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_verify() in /home/bialvmlq/public_html/panel/login.php on line 14 "

Non-Working Code below:

```
< ?php

session_start();

//Username:test
//Password:test

if(!empty($_POST)) {
  $isim = $_POST['login'];
$sifre = $_POST['password'];

 var_dump($isim, $sifre);

 if($isim == 'test' && password_verify($sifre,      ' $2y$10$ZzV6jDI5HU.SUrpx0AFoQe9r49NI.NkpH5OhZ28Ug4G0MnmdVKaFy')) {
 $_SESSION['auth'] = 1;

 header('Location: main.php');
 exit;
 }
}

?>
```

An answer and help would be appreciated.

Comment: And the version of PHP that you're running?

Comment: PHP version currently used: native (5.4)

Comment: [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) requires PHP >= 5.5.0, or include the [userland implementation](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: @MarkBaker, Genius Indeed. You solved my 3 days Problem. 
It worked. Thanks Indeed

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
    password_verify()
requires PHP version 5.5.0 (according to Mark Baker).
Once this is updated and saved, navigate to the login.php, It worked !!
Solved..

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted, this will prevent the question from showing unanswered.